# mysql stopped working after no free space on file system [corruption]

Tags: mysql, mariadb, configuration, corruption, handler-socket

I am experiencing the following error when launching MySQL.

> can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
> Check that mysqld is running and that the socket '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!`

Basically, I have noticed that there is no free space on the partition where MySQL is installed. I freed some space and rebooted, but same error.

I have also tried other solutions I've found on Google, such as: safe mode, restarting services, changing ip address. But none of these have worked.

By the way, the file `/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock` is not present.

P.S. I am using MariaDB

[EDIT]

From the logs it looks like the DB got corrupted:

[ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of tablespace .... you may have to recover from a backup

Comment: Please run `ps -ef | grep mysql | grep -v grep`. Do you see mysqld processes running ???

Comment: You'll want to look at the MySQL error log contents.

Comment: Look like the log is telling you that you should restore from your most recent successful backup. That's your answer. I suggest you restore to a server with a larger storage volume.

Comment: I have a backup of my specific application DB only. I assume this means I have to uninstall mysql, reinstall it and restore that application DB